# C# Unable to find entry point on unmangled C++ library

Tags: c#, c++, c

I'm getting the error
"Unable to find an entry point named 'foo' in DLL 'example.dll'".

I used depends.exe and DUMPBIN.exe. The function is there and its name is unmangled.

Can you see anything particularly wrong with this?

Here is the C++ code.

```
//example.cpp
//Using Multibyte Char Set. (if that matters)
//Edit: I can not change this code.
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) int foo(const char *name)
{
...
}
```

Here is the C# code.

```
//importing.cs
public static class ImportClass
{
[DllImport("example.dll")]
public static extern int foo(string name)
}
```

I can't modify the C++, it was provided by an external source who forbids it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: change the spec from _declspec to __stdcall

Comment: I forgot to mention. I can't change any of the C++ code. It was given to me from an external source that forbids tampering with it.

Comment: Then you can't do nothing, the problem is in the dll.

Comment: Man.. That's too bad. Would it be possible for me to create a C++ wrapper to call the function from the dll and then use _stdcall in the wrapper?

Comment: declspec is used to export the function from the dll. It is not the calling convention. The calling convention is probably _stdcall if not specified otherwise.

Comment: If the calling convention of the dll isn't _stdcall, you can try specifying the calling convention attribute in DLLImport

Comment: You can definitely wrap the C++ in your own C++ code with the required calling convention if you don't find a solution using DLLImport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.callingconvention(v=vs.100).aspx), the default calling convention of a method imported via DLL Import is `__stdcall`, meaning it won't be able to find your `__declspec` method. Try <strike>changing it to `__stdcall` or</strike> making your DLLImport specify the [CallingConvention.Cdecl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention(v=vs.100).aspx)

As mentioned, name mangling may also be a problem, assuming the library you're calling didn't declare the method with an `EXPORTS` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You might be a victim of `Name Mangling` here.
[Wikipedia Name Mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)

First Use `dumpbin.exe` to list the definitions exported by your dll.

```
eg: `dumpbin.exe /EXPORTS example.dll`
```

Verify the name of the function that's exported.

Next use the DLL Import like this:

```
[DllImport("example.dll", EntryPoint = @"TheNameFrom DumpBin goes here")]
```

You might also want to look up the `CallingConvention` attribute as well.

Comment: his c++ code say extern "C" (which disables c++ name munging)

Comment: Yes most of the documents say so, but I have seen in practice that the compilers usually prefix function names with something. eg: an `underscore`, or modify them ever so slightly by changing the casing of the names. Its usually best to verify using `dumpbin` for Entry Point errors.

Comment: Even Dumpbin.exe shows that they are unmangled. I'm going to go with the wrapper technique and report back with results.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use duplicate file names.

My program was loading the wrong "example.dll"; one that didn't have foo().

I'm really sorry for all the trouble guys.